# @types/node and VS Code: IntelliSense not working because of comment formatting

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I use Visual Studio Code and @types/node (7.0.8) but it seems that some functions etc. have a wrong formatted code comment and therefore Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio 2017 won't show any quickinfos in IntelliSense.

example

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
fs.unlink
```

When I type fs.unlink VS Code display the function signature but not the comment whitch is defined in

```
./node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts
```

on line 2400

```
/*
 * Asynchronous unlink - deletes the file specified in {path}
 *
 * @param path
 * @param callback No arguments other than a possible exception are given to the completion callback.
 */
 export function unlink(path: string | Buffer, callback?: (err?: NodeJS.ErrnoException) => void): void;
```

The culprit here is the first line which misses an asterisk.
The correct notation would be

```
/**
```

As soon as I change index.d.ts like that, I get working IntelliSense.
Some functions are commented corretly while others are not.

Am I doing something wrong here? (are those functions not meant to be used despite being exported)
Is it an error in @types/node and if so are there ways to teach VS Code to parse those comments?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work on TS and JS support for VSCode. The use of `/*` instead of `/**` looks like a bug in the node `d.ts` type definition. As far as I know, there is no way to configure TypeScript or VSCode to treat plain old `/*` comments as documentation comments.

I've submitted a PR with the fix: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/15285